# RTP over TCP with single port

Tags: tcp, webrtc

I am creating media server using WebRTC for video conferencing. As you might know when a user connects to the server two ports will be opened on the server side. RTP and RTCP ports over TCP. Thus, media server will need wide-range of available ports. The case here is not about multiplexing RTP and RTCP ports.

Assume that the media server is behind firewall and ports are blocked so that cannot open wide-range of ports. For example, the media server will use 8080 for signalling and 443 for RTP/RTCP. All video traffic will flow into 443 on the server side.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you looking for Multiple RTP/RTCP session data receive on the same port or only Single RTP/RTCP session on same port - As this is media server.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, and many media servers provide that feature.
Wowza enables single port for WebRTC over TCP; Unreal Media Server enables single port for WebRTC over TCP and for WebRTC over UDP as well.

Technically, it's quite challenging to develop such a feature; especially for providing single port for WebRTC over UDP. You need to relay incoming WebRTC traffic, arriving to your single port, to internal endpoints of particular RTCPeerConnections in the server. Initial Stun requests carry information that helps you find the right context and map the external to internal.

Comment: Can we receive multiple rtp session data on single port of media server.

Comment: Yes; that's what the question was

Comment: What would be the max number of RTP/RTCP sessions that can be supported on single port ( max bitrate per session). what would be the socket buffer size to support this.

Comment: You are relaying the incoming data to internal sockets of individual RTCPeerConnections, so practically you are just copying the data from this single socket buffer to individual socket buffers. So yes, this single socket buffer should be big; 1000 sessions should be supported no problem.